# Blender Keeps Creating Numerous Invisible Objects

Tags: modeling, objects

starting noticing that my blender projects have 100s of invisible objects in them, which keep growing every time I edit/save the project. Anyone know how I can find and delete these invisible objects?

[image: Invisible Objects]

[image: Invisible Objects View]

Here is a sample blend project - could not get it under 30MB to upload it on blend-exchange: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsBY7Z_lQQ0qNITnvexc233jmPIf_Ag_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The first image - Are you *Appending* some object from another blend file to a new one seen on the second image and this object comes with others that are listed in Outliner, but not visible in 3D Viewport?

Comment: @vklidu yes, this is the situation - I am appending objects from another blend file but seems these invisible objects keep growing each time I open/edit the blend file.

Comment: What is at Layer 1? Probably better if you can share sample source file. Create a file with a Cube (Save, Close) than open a new file and try to Append the Cube from previously saved file. If that works fine would be better if you can [share a file](https://blend-exchange.com) that you are using as source (you are append from) ... to see what structure is there. Ideally if you can delete all parts that doesn't participate on the issue (it would be lighter to upload and easier for us to understand to this file. Thanks

Comment: @vklidu I had to share the file on Google Drive. Link is in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

From given file I can see two things ...

- 80 MB file contains 20 MB of *Orphan Data* (materials and images)

[image]

- and than a weird thing ...under *Outliner > Blend File* there are four objects with materials that take the rest of MB.

[image]

To clean the file from those right click on each **object** (Cube.0011 ... .0014) and choose *Delete*. Those data (objects and materials) are still kept in blender under *Outliner > Orphan data*, Blender keeps it for next file opening (as some kind of backup). Open save it twice because first open-save delete material orphan data second delete images of these materials.

Why are mentioned objects kept in file I can't say, they are not linked, they are not marked as *Faked User* ... I don't see any relationship for those *Data Blocks* (that you can study closer in Outliner too) to behave like that.

- If there will still persist some images go to *File > External Data > Unpack*.

---

This was about how to store them in the blend, but you were speaking about appending into a new file ... How does that happened for you?

When I try to Append like Cube.0011 into a new file it seams to be fine. The only one weird thing here is light blue color of origin the appended object ... should be orange as outline. Light blue color is referring to **Linked** object (that is not) ...